# getting data without matching full string in elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

my data is stored in the elastic search  below format

```
 {
            "_index": "wallet",
            "_type": "wallet",
            "_id": "5dfcbe0a6ca963f84470d852",
            "_score": 0.69321066,
            "_source": {
                "email": "test20011@gmail.com",
                "wallet": "test20011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com",
                "countryCode": "+91",
                "phone": "7916318809",
                "name": "test20011"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "wallet",
            "_type": "wallet",
            "_id": "5dfcbe0a6ca9634d1c70d856",
            "_score": 0.69321066,
            "_source": {
                "email": "test50011@gmail.com",
                "wallet": "test50011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com",
                "countryCode": "+91",
                "phone": "3483330496",
                "name": "test50011"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "wallet",
            "_type": "wallet",
            "_id": "5dfcbe0a6ca96304b370d857",
            "_score": 0.69321066,
            "_source": {
                "email": "test110021@gmail.com",
                "wallet": "test110021@operatorqa2.akeodev.com",
                "countryCode": "+91",
                "phone": "2744697207",
                "name": "test110021"
            }
        }
```

The record should not find if we are using below query

```
   {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "wallet": {
                            "query": "operatorqa2.akeodev.com",
                             "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "email": {
                            "query": "operatorqa2.akeodev.com",
                                "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

the record should find if I am passing below Query

```
    {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "wallet": {
                            "query": "test20011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com",
                             "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "email": {
                            "query": "test20011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com",
                                "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have created the index on the email and wallet field.
whenever users searching data by email or wallet and I am not sure that whatever string is sending by the user it's email or wallet so I am using `bool`.

the record should find if a user sends the full Email address or full Wallet Address.
Please help me to find a solution

Comment: You try to search for the same string (an email address) in two different fields (email & wallet). Unfortunately I struggle understanding `if we are using below string...` . Can you please reword your question & expectation?

Comment: Can you please add mapping of your ES index and also let us know which version of ES ur using ??

Comment: Hi, @DanielSchneiter

I have an index on 
the wallet and email field. I am getting  "operatorqa2.akeodev.com" from the user and I need to search value from the wallet or email field. 

whatever string getting from the user, this string is not excitedly matching with any of the data in my ES but stile I am getting data.  

and my requirement is if the user sends the full string like "test110011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com"  then the record must come 
 
But if I am gating data  "operatorqa2.akeodev.com". from the user then record should not find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by the other community members, when asking questions like this you should specify the version of Elasticsearch you are using and also provide the mapping.

Starting with Elasticsearch version 5 with default mappings you would only need to change your query to query against the exact version of the field rather than the analyzed version. By default Elasticsearch maps strings to a multi-field of type `text` (analyzed, for full-text search) and `keyword` (not-analyzed, for exact match search). In your query you would then query against the `<fieldname>.keyword`-fields:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "wallet.keyword": "test20011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "email.keyword": "test20011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you are on an Elasticsearch version prior to version 5, change the index-property from `analyzed` to `not_analyzed` and re-index your data.

Mapping snippet:

```
{
  "email": {
    "type" "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

Your query would still not need to use the `and`-operator. It will look identical to the query I posted above, with the exception that you have to query against the `email` and `wallet`-fields, and not `email.keyword` and `wallet.keyword`.

I can recommend you the following blog post from Elastic related to that topic: [Strings are dead, long live strings!](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working fine for me 
and my ES version is 7.4.2

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have a mapping to your index schema, I am assuming you are using ES defaults(you can get this using [mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html)) and in your case, `wallet` and `email` fields would be defined as `text` with default analyzer which is the standard analyzer.

This analyzer wouldn't recognize these text as mail-ids and would create three tokens for `test50011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com` which you can check using the [analyze APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

http://localhost:9200/_analyze?text=test50011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com&tokenizer=standard

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test50011",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "operatorqa2",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 21,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "akeodev.com",
      "start_offset": 22,
      "end_offset": 33,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

What you need here is [custom analyzer for mails using UAX URI Mail tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html) which is used for email fields. This would generate a proper token(just 1) for `test50011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com` as shown below:

http://localhost:9200/_analyze?text=test50011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com&tokenizer=uax_url_email

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test50011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 33,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Now as you can see it's not splitting `test50011@operatorqa2.akeodev.com`, hence when you search using your same query it would also generate the same token and ES works on a token to token match.

Let me know if you need any help, its very simple to setup and use.